# How can I refresh a ASP.NET MVC UserControl with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I have a UserControl that binds directly to database, that is, it's not rendered by any Action. It works independly.

But, from times to times I have to refresh it to get new information from database.
I've already worked with refreshing UserControls in jQuery via Ajax, but in all of these cases, I had a Action to make the service.

But, this time I don't have a Action since this UC gets its information directly.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You need to call an action that returns the controls view. Example:

```
public ActionResult GetFooControl()
{
   return View("~/Views/Shared/Foo.ascx");
}
```

Then use the jQuery's load function to refresh the inner HTML for the control's container.

```
$('#mycontrolContainer').load('../MyController/GetFooControl');
```

Comment: José, I ended to use the load() but I used an Action just to call this UC... I don't know why it didn't work it for me without the Action, but thanks anyway!