# Reload MVC2 user control with jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I know I've had a ton of questions today, but still trying to get everything under control learning MVC 2 tie right way. Before I get into the question I already tried the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826450/how-can-i-refresh-a-asp-net-mvc-usercontrol-with-jquery) but I get an 500 internal server error.

So here's what I'm trying to do, I give the user the ability to select from a list of skills (loaded in a ListView user control) or add a new one to the list and select that. The adding new one is completed (using a WCF service & jQuery) but now I'm trying to reload the skills user control.

According to the solution I linked to I added an action to my AccountController

```
public ActionResult GetSkillControl()
{
    return View("~/Views/Shared/SkillsListView.ascx");
}
```

I have the control inside a span (so it has a container)

```
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;"><label for="SkillsListView" title="Skills">Skills:</label></td>
    <td class="regElements"><span id="SkillListViewContainer"> <% Html.RenderPartial("SkillsListView"); %></span><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Skills, "*")%><br />
    <span id="AddSkillError"></span>
    Add: <input type="text" id="NewSkill" class="inputbox" style="width:75px;" />&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Add" id="AddSkill" name="AddSkill" /></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

And in my jQuery ajax call I have

```
success: function () {
    $('#SkillListViewContainer').load('../AccountController/GetSkillControl');
}
```

It's when it reaches that point that the JavaScript console in Chrome shows it returns a 500 internal server error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the standard routes in ASP.NET MVC, try "/Account/GetSkillControl".  Anything you use from jQuery's load method must be a valid URL.  The route engine is looking or Account and not AccountController.  Also by using the leading "/" it will resolving from the root of the site.